# passing a prop from index into header component

Tags: react-native

I'm following a udemy tutorial on react-native.

I'm trying to pass a prop from my index.js into my header.js.  The header should say, "Albums".  But is is always showing up blank.

If I remove **{props.headerText}** from header.js and replace it with

"Albums"

then it works.  But I'm trying to make the component reusable per the tutorial instructions.

note: I'm using Create React Native App and this is on an android emulator.
App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/header';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header />
    );
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/header';

const App = () => (
    <Header headerText={'Albums'} />
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Header = (props) => {
    const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <View style={viewStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    headerStyle: {
        fontSize: 20
    }
  };

  export default Header;
```

Am I missing anything?  I've been over and over each file line by line and I can't find any issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is nothing to fix. Your code works! Remember: index.js is the entry point so App.js is not used at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you

```js
const Header = ({props}) => {
    const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <View style={viewStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

And to pass props ;

```js
const App = () => (
    <Header props={someProps} />
);
```

Comment: Please let me know if it does not work as you expected. Can you please mark the answer as correct if it works well ?

Comment: Do not call a prop `props` this will lead to confusion.